# How do I handle application views in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex

I have a Flex application with three different views. Only one view is shown at a time, and the choice of view depends on what part of the application the user is working with. If it had been an ordinary HTML webapp I would have created three different HTML-templates/pages  for each view.

What is the recommended way to handle such application views in Flex?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behavior you want is usually accomplished by using a ViewStack component.  In MXML you declare child containers for each view you want, but only one gets shown at a time.  You can change which one is shown programmatically whenever conditions are met by setting selectedIndex on your ViewStack.  By default the first child container is displayed when run.  Another approach is to declare and use states in your container and change currentState whenever you need to change the view.  Hope that helps.